# Hanlding Dynamic multi-lingual content in ASP.NET (Roman, Hindi & Urdu)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a website in ASP.NET which handles multiple languages. My content is in three languages: Roman, Urdu and English.The content will be dynamic.

**For example**, if a user visits my website and he searches on website for a specific post. Then the user wants to change the language preference, its content will change dynamically as a user selects different language from menu. Then he searches for another post and wants to change language preference to some other language, the content must be translated again into the newly selected language.
I can afford to insert separate data for each of the language in database but i am not sure if this works and how this works (**how to create db design for such solution and how to store and retrieve same data in multiple languages in db**).

I have been looking at some threads on different platforms but the solutions I have come across with are not feasible for my scenario.
One solution is to use Google Translate, but I need quality translation and Google Translate does not perform well on Roman Language.
Another most encouraged solution for ASP.NET is to use resource files (key-value pairs for content). Using Resource files for small websites where content is static works perfectly fine, but the resource files are not salable and would not work for my scenario as the content I am dealing with is completely dynamic.

Please let me know if there is a solution. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for good translation service - you should try some other site for this type of question as recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: refer this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-multiple-languages-in-asp-net-mvc-4-5-framework/

Comment: @HienNguyen I have visited this link already. This link focuses on multi-lingual static content where I am trying to solve problem for dynamic content.
My content is huge and I cannot create Key-Value pairs for such huge data as mentioned in the link.